# Extracting Data from HL7 Files in Talend

Tags: talend, hl7, data-integration

I am trying to read data from HL7 files using Talend.
The component that I am using is tHl7Input component.

Job :

[image]

The sample file that I am using is below:

```
MSH|^~\&|CERNER||PriorityHealth||||ORU^R01|Q479004375T431430612|P|2.3|
PID|||001677980||SMITH^CURTIS||19680219|M||||||||||929645156318|123456789|
PD1||||1234567890^LAST^FIRST^M^^^^^NPI|
OBR|1|341856649^HNAM_ORDERID|000002006326002362|648088^Basic Metabolic Panel|||20061122151600|||||||||1620^Hooker^Robert^L||||||20061122154733|||F|||||||||||20061122140000|
```

Hl7 Component Configuration:

[image]

But I am not able to extract the data from it.

Output which I am getting with null values:
[image]
I have read the forum of Talend to read the Hl7 files, but i not not able to extract the same.
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tHL7Input

Any inputs on this would be helpfull.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a screenshot of the job, the mapping, and the output you currently get.

Comment: I am just trying to read the data from the file which is in HL7 format. Can you just guide me on how to read the file.

Comment: Not possible without more information.

Comment: @tobi6 I have provided the job screenshots. Can you please help on this.

Comment: First of all, the mapping which is visible seems fine. Also, you *can* extract data, at least for the *MSH* part. Please rename *tLogRowX* to *logMSH* and *logPID*, accordingly. Also, you should replace all `newColumnX` with the correct mapping names [for HL7](https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources) to make things easier to read. Additionally, add an image for the *PID* mapping, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never use Talend. This is based on the screenshots you have given.

Your mappings are off by +1.

MSH.1 should hardcode to | (pipe).

MSH.2 should map to newColumn4.

MSH.3 should map to Name1, and output shall be Cerner.

MSH.4 should map to Name3, and output will be null as there is nothing in the message.

So on and so forth.

You need to change your data map to use accurate hl7 component names - Encoding characters, Sending Application etc. Otherwise, at the end of assignment you will end up confused.

Comment: I think the same for component names.

Comment: @sid : So does this mean that either I should have complete knowledge about hl7 files then only I can start using them in thl7  components.
Also in each of the MSH there are many sub groups. How do I know which subgroup to map to my output.

Comment: You at least need elementary knowledge of HL7, the how-to read part, and where is the information located. HL7 is a messaging standard, everything has a specific placeholder. [You can start here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423191618/http://www.mexi.be/documents/hl7/httoc.htm)

Comment: @Sid I have accepted the concept that you have suggested. Thanks